# Split a Directory Path (String ) into two strings using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am new at Powershell and I have spent a whole day working out this how to split a string
I have this string path

```
RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

I want to split this into two strings so that the first string holds the RootFolder and the second string has rest of the string.

**E.g:  RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3**

```
$rootFolder = RootFolder 
$subFolders = Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$root, $path = "RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3".Split("\", 2)` leaves you with `$root # --> RootFolder` and `$path # --> Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3`

Comment: there is a cmdlet for that >>> `Get-Help Split-Path -Parameter *` <<< [*grin*] look specifically at 'qualifier', 'parent', & 'leaf'. also, if the item is a FileInfo or DirInfo object, look at the `.Root`, `.Parent`, and `.Directory.Parent` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the split operator:

`$splitPath = 'RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3' -split '\\', 2`

Which gives this output:

```
$splitPath

RootFolder
Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

You can access the individual parts like this:

```
$splitPath[0]

RootFolder
```

If the path begins with a drive letter (e.g. `C:\RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3`) and you want to ignore it, just increase the substring count:

```
$splitPath = 'C:\RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3' -split '\\', 3


$splitPath

C:
RootFolder
Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

Comment: thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few methods for you:

Using the string's `Split()` method

```
$root, $path = "RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3".Split("\", 2)

$root # --> RootFolder
$path # --> Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

Using the string's `IndexOf()` method

```
$folder = "RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3"
$index = $folder.IndexOf("\")
$root  = $folder.Substring(0, $index)
$path  = $folder.Substring($index + 1)

$root # --> RootFolder
$path # --> Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```

Or even something like

```
$folder = "RootFolder\Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3" -split '\\'
$root   = $folder[0]
$path   = $folder[1..($folder.Count -1)] -join '\'

$root # --> RootFolder
$path # --> Subfolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3
```